# How to refactor GraphQL schema using "graphql-compose-elasticsearch" to tranform GraphQL query into Elasticsearch query?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, graphql

I was hosting my data using json server on `localhost:3000`(REST api) and using GraphQL to fetch data, and now I'd like to move data into a Elastic Search server, and I still want to use GraphQL as API gateway. I tried this `graphql-compose-elasticsearch` library to use GraphQL as a proxy for ElasticSearch.
https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-elasticsearch

In my original GraphQL schema, I defined types, root query, resolvers. The code is like this:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const axios = require('axios');

const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLBoolean,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLNonNull
} = graphql;

const RoomType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RoomType',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    roomName: { type: GraphQLString },
    roomNumber: { type: GraphQLString },
    floorId: { type: GraphQLInt },
    hasImages: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    hasGLTF: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    hasPhotogrammetry: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    hasPointClouds: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    roomDescription: { type: GraphQLString },
    floor: {
      type: FloorType,
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        return axios
          .get(`http://localhost:3000/floors/${parentValue.floorId}`)
          .then((resp) => resp.data);
      }
    },
    assets: {
      type: new GraphQLList(AssetType),
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        return axios
          .get(`http://localhost:3000/rooms/${parentValue.id}/assets`)
          .then((resp) => resp.data);
      }
    }
  })
});

const FloorType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'FloorType',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    floorName: { type: GraphQLString },
    floorDescription: { type: GraphQLString },
    rooms: {
      type: new GraphQLList(RoomType),
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        return axios
          .get(`http://localhost:3000/floors/${parentValue.id}/rooms`)
          .then((resp) => resp.data);
      }
    }
  })
});

const AssetType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'AssetType',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    category: { type: GraphQLString },
    assetName: { type: GraphQLString },
    assetNumber: { type: GraphQLString },
    roomId: { type: GraphQLString },
    location: { type: GraphQLString },
    isHeritageAsset: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    hasImages: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    hasGLTF: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    hasPhotogrammetry: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    hasPointClouds: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    assetDescription: { type: GraphQLString },
    room: {
      type: RoomType,
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        return axios
          .get(`http://localhost:3000/rooms/${parentValue.roomId}`)
          .then((resp) => resp.data);
      }
    }
  })
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    getRoom: {
      type: RoomType,
      args: { id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) } },
      resolve(parentValue, { id }) {
        return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/rooms/${id}`).then((resp) => resp.data);
      }
    },
    getFloor: {
      type: FloorType,
      args: { id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) } },
      resolve(parentValue, { id }) {
        return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/floors/${id}`).then((resp) => resp.data); //to make it compatible between axios and graphql, a workaround
      }
    },
    getAsset: {
      type: AssetType,
      args: { id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) } },
      resolve(parentValue, { id }) {
        return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/assets/${id}`).then((resp) => resp.data); //to make it compatible between axios and graphql, a workaround
      }
    },
    getAllRooms: {
      type: new GraphQLList(RoomType),
      resolve() {
        return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/rooms`).then((resp) => resp.data);
      }
    },
    getAllAssets: {
      type: new GraphQLList(AssetType),
      resolve() {
        return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/assets`).then((resp) => resp.data);
      }
    },
    getAllFloors: {
      type: new GraphQLList(FloorType),
      resolve() {
        return axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/floors`).then((resp) => resp.data);
      }
    }
  }
});

//expose this to the rest of the application
module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery
});
```

For Elasticsearch, the version is 7.0. I'm running on `localhost:9200`, and I have 3 indices, `rooms`, `floors`, and `assets`, and each of the index have a mapping. I tried to code like this:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const graphql_compose_elasticsearch = require('graphql-compose-elasticsearch');
const { elasticApiFieldConfig, composeWithElastic } = graphql_compose_elasticsearch;
const { GraphQLSchema, GraphQLObjectType } = graphql;
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

// Mapping obtained from ElasticSearch server
const floor_mapping = {
  properties: {
    floorId: {
      type: 'text',
      fields: {
        keyword: {
          type: 'keyword',
          ignore_above: 256
        }
      }
    },
    hasGLTF: {
      type: 'boolean'
    },
    hasImages: {
      type: 'boolean'
    },
    hasPhotogrammetry: {
      type: 'boolean'
    },
    hasPointClouds: {
      type: 'boolean'
    },
    roomDescription: {
      type: 'text',
      fields: {
        keyword: {
          type: 'keyword',
          ignore_above: 256
        }
      }
    },
    roomName: {
      type: 'text',
      fields: {
        keyword: {
          type: 'keyword',
          ignore_above: 256
        }
      }
    },
    roomNumber: {
      type: 'text',
      fields: {
        keyword: {
          type: 'keyword',
          ignore_above: 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const room_mapping = {
  //similar
};

const asset_mapping = {
 //similar
};

const Room = composeWithElastic({
  graphqlTypeName: 'RoomType',
  elasticIndex: 'rooms',
  elasticType: '_doc',
  elasticMapping: room_mapping,
  elasticClient: new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'http://localhost:9200',
    apiVersion: '7.0'
  })
});

const Floor = composeWithElastic({
  graphqlTypeName: 'FloorType',
  elasticIndex: 'floors',
  elasticType: '_doc',
  elasticMapping: floor_mapping,
  elasticClient: new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'http://localhost:9200',
    apiVersion: '7.0'
  })
});

const Asset = composeWithElastic({
  graphqlTypeName: 'AssetType',
  elasticIndex: 'assets',
  elasticType: '_doc',
  elasticMapping: asset_mapping,
  elasticClient: new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'http://localhost:9200',
    apiVersion: '7.0'
  })
});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
      roomSearch: Room.getResolver('search').getFieldConfig(),
      roomSearchConnection: Room.getResolver('searchConnection').getFieldConfig(),
      elastic70: elasticApiFieldConfig({
        host: 'http://localhost:9200',
        apiVersion: '7.0'
      })
    }
  })
});

module.default = { schema };
```

server.js is like this:

```
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
const { schema } = require('./schema/schema_es');
// const schema = require('./schema/schema');
var cors = require('cors');
const server = require('express')();

//allow cross-origin
server.use(
  '/',
  cors(),
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true,
    formatError: (error) => ({
      message: error.message,
      stack: error.stack.split('\n')
    })
  })
);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6060;
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

I restarted the servers, and here is the error I got 
`invariant.esm.js:31 [GraphQL error]: Message: GraphQL middleware options must contain a schema., Location: undefined, Path: undefined`

I have no idea how to how to transfrom graphql schema, rootquery..etc into ES query using this `graphql-compose-elasticsearch`, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to get any headway into this ? I am also in a similar situation and have been asked to use graphql-compose and its plugins and I am not sure at all how to refactor existing resolvers and whats the use case .. :D !